# Is 'gloomy sunlight' an oxymoron?

Tags: word-usage

Is 'gloomy sunlight' an oxymoron?

I don't see how its an oxymoron. I am not sure how else to phrase this question.

Comment: It is more of a paradox.

Comment: @Kris Surely that's what an oxymoron is.

Comment: @skymninge Surely that's what an oxymoron is. There seem to be some people who confuse 'oxymoron' (apparent contradiction which on deeper analysis makes sense [ie paradox]; expressed succinctly) with 'contradiction in terms' (true contradiction).

Comment: Back when I learned stylistic devices, we were told in this context there is a difference between an oxymoron and a paradox. Unfortunately, I can only find german sources for this, maybe it is a german language specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not.  As others have said "gloomy" could be used in the emotional sense, but even if it is meant to represent "darkness" this is not an oxymoron, but a simple descriptive phrase.  Sunlight can be dim or gloomy if it is blocked by trees, clouds, fog, or other such environmental effects.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, it does but also it doesn't.

Gloomy can also be used as a form of emotion or expression. As an emotion, it cannot be an example as the opposite of sunlight.

Or that's just how I see it.

Comment: It does but it doesn't? Do you mean *it is but it isn't*?

Answer (score 0):

"Gloom" is sometimes used to mean "darkness", which would make it an oxymoron.

If you're using gloomy to refer to the mood you feel when seeing it, it isn't necessarily an oxymoron -- but since most folks consider sunlight pleasant, you need to say something more than that to justify the combination. Maybe you're depressed, or a goth, and everything fills you with ennui. Or maybe you're just a vampire or other nocturnal creature and you consider sunlight a nasty thing. But until you explain it, the phrase is going to sound self-contradictory at best, like foul-tasting sugar or hot ice.

Answer (score 0):

[Oxymoron](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Oxymoron)

> A rhetorical figure in which incongruous or contradictory terms are combined, as in a deafening silence and a mournful optimist.

[Gloomy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Gloomy)

> 1. dark or dim: gloomy skies.
> 2. causing gloom; depressing: a gloomy prospect.
> 3. filled with or showing gloom; melancholy: a gloomy mood.

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com

It  appears it is, you are using two terms that are apparently incongruous to create an effect of surprise probably to attract the reader's attention.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for me to define the term 'oxymoron', but I recognize it when I see it. It's usually a sentence employing contradictory terms, as Josh61 pointed out.

Examples: 'At the party the room was filled with a silence like the thunder of guns. (Someone had said or done something that shocked the guests into total silence.)

Or Russel Baker's description of the 1968 Republican Convention in the Miami Beach Convention Hall: 'The atmosphere was crackling with tedium when the Republican party assembled last night to pick itself a president. Boredom had been building relentlessly all week, reaching an intensity that was scarcely bearable.'